# Index similar entries in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a column of data (easily imported from Google Docs thanks to [gspread](http://burnash.github.com/gspread/userguide.html#getting-the-entire-row-or-column)) that I'd like to intelligently align. I ingest entries into a dictionary. Input can include email, twitter handle or a blog URL. For example:

`mike.j@gmail.com

@mikej45

j.mike@world.eu

_http://tumblr.com/mikej45`

Right now, the "dumb" version is:

```
def NomineeCount(spreadsheet):
    worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1
    nominees = worksheet.col_values(6) # F = 6
    unique_nominees = {}
    for c in nominees:
        pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
        c = re.sub(pattern, '', c)
        if unique_nominees.has_key(c) == True: # If we already have the name
            unique_nominees[c] += 1
        else:
            unique_nominees[c] = 1

        # Print out the alphabetical list of nominees with leading vote count
        for w in sorted(unique_nominees.keys()):
        print string.rjust(str(unique_nominees[w]), 2)+ "  " + w

        return nominees
```

What's an efficient(-ish) way to add in some smarts during the if process?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
unique_nominees = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
unique_nominees[c] += 1
```